# Obtaining factor scores from a factor analysis of mixed types (both ordinal and scale) variables

Tags: r, spss, factor-analysis, psychometrics

I have to analyze a data set having both ordinal and scale variables. What I was trying to do was to factor analyze the data. The data was in SPSS. But I think SPSS factor analyzes the data by calculating Pearson's correlation by default which might be misleading as my data set contains mixed types of variables. I could use `hetcor` in the R package `polycor` and then use the correlation matrix as an input for factor analysis using the commands in package `psych`. But most of the commands do not provide me with factor scores which is very important to obtain for the purpose of my analysis. This is because my input is the heterogeneous correlation matrix, not the data itself. I heard that using `fa.poly` would give me the factor scores. But whenever I run this command it produces the following:

```
> fa.poly(dat,nfactor=4,rotate="varimax")
 Polychoric |.
```

How can I extract the factor scores?

Do I have any alternative? For your convenience to answer this here is [the data](http://www.4shared.com/file/U0kF2JRK/4factoranalysis.html). I need the factor scores to be calculated. What do you think should be an appropriate procedure?

Comment: What is important to know is what you intend to do with factor scores. Is this is convenient way to summarize individual differences as simple composite scores, or do you want to factor out scale and item scores because there's an underlying measurement model that would make sense in your context?

Comment: Dear chl, I want to see if the factors are related (or if used as regressors, affect) some other observed variables. Say, to see if profit is related to one of the factors. A correlation measure can do it, I guess. And if regressed on profit, then I may also see if the factors affect profit. I have some other variables except from profit for the same purpose too.

Comment: I don't know R but I can suppose the program refuses to compute factor scores because some of your variables are ordinal. You see, polychoric correlations are _implied_ Pearson correlations, you don't have data in your set _directly_ tied to them. How can factor scores be computed in such a case - I personally don't know yet. Perhaps it is possible by a special algorithm, different from that traditionally used in computation factor scores when all variables are scale.

Comment: Blain, if you are determined to treat some variables as ordinal why not try _another approach_ than via polychoric correlations? I mean using monotonic transformation of ordinal variables into scale variables via Categorical PCA (available in SPSS) and using then standard Factor analysis (also in SPSS). That would be easier.

Comment: @ttnphns, I think that is a great idea! I don't know much about it and also don't know how to implement this in SPSS. I am looking at the theories, could you please write something on its implementation in SPSS for me? I mean on how do I do it?

Comment: In SPSS, CatPCA is a part of Categories Module. Check if you have menu item Data Reduction > Optimal Scaling. If you don't have it, that means you don't have the module installed. A good and simple description and example of CatPCA usage is [here](http://web.it.nctu.edu.tw/~qtqm/qtqmpapers/2010V7N2/2010V7N2_F1.pdf).

Comment: @ttnphns, thank you so much. The reference was really helpful. I was trying to understand what you suggested. I am sorry to ask again, but did you mean that I should select only the ordinal variables first for CATPCA, save the transformed variables (which were ordinal before) to the original data set and then combining them with the original scale variables run standard factor analysis? Have I understood it properly? If I have then what should be the number of dimensions for CATPCA? Should it be equal to the number of factors believed to exist?

Comment: No, you must take all, both ordinal and scale, variables in CATPCA. If you want only ordinal of them to be transformed into scale type _non-linearly_, specify spline ordinal or ordinal level for them and numeric level for the ones that are already scale for you (they will be transformed linearly). `Should it be equal to the number of factors believed to exist?` Yes. If you want just PCA, you don't have to run FACTOR afterwards: CATPCA _is_ transformation-then-PCA. Run FACTOR with the transformed variables if you want factor analysis per se (implying communalities/uniqness).